# XSLT: XML to XML transformation using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I need some help to achieve a solution to convert xml to xml using xslt. 
Below are the details

Input xml

```
<FileDetailRecord>
<Detail number="1">
<CONSUMERKEY>89NpvkBIi0TLxAssskdHtIETUa</CONSUMERKEY>
<API>Test_API</API>
<APIPUBLISHER>admin</APIPUBLISHER>
<RESOURCEPATH>/zones/{zoning}</RESOURCEPATH>
<TOTAL_REQUEST_COUNT>1</TOTAL_REQUEST_COUNT>
<USERID>xyz@abc.super</USERID>
<TIME>2018-09-25 11:09</TIME>
</Detail>
<Detail number="2">
<CONSUMERKEY>87878jhkhkhskdHtIETUa</CONSUMERKEY>
<API>TestTest_API</API>
<APIPUBLISHER>admin</APIPUBLISHER>
<RESOURCEPATH>/zoneflow/{matrix}/{zoning}</RESOURCEPATH>
<TOTAL_REQUEST_COUNT>1</TOTAL_REQUEST_COUNT>
<USERID>abc@abc.super</USERID>
<TIME>2018-09-25 10:23</TIME>
</Detail>
</FileDetailRecord>
```

I need to covert this xml to into . It has some dummy value as well which I have already mentioned in ().. Also the time which is coming from input file has to be included with seconds as well (mentioned in the brackets)

```
<Detail1>
<TransactionID>89NpvkBIi0TLxAssskdHtIETUa</TransactionID>
<USERID>xyz@abc.super</USERID>
<APIPUBLISHER>admin</APIPUBLISHER>
<API>Test_API_/zones/{zoning}</API>
<Hits>1</Hits>
<Starttime>2018-09-12 11:09:17</Starttime> (any time is ok as this value is 
not required at the target)
<EndTime>2018-09-12 11:09:17</EndTime>   (any time is ok as this value is 
not required at the target)
<Rate>10</Rate> (any value is ok as this value is not required at the 
target)
<Amount>90</Amount>  (any value is ok as this value is not required at the 
target)
<Currency>EURO</Currency>
<Channel1>test</Channel1>
<Channel2>time</Channel2>
<Region>dummy</Region>
<TIME>2018-09-25 11:09:12</TIME> (this value has seconds also as it was not 
there in input file)
<Share>dumy</Share> (any value is ok as this value is not required at the 
target)
<Method>dummy</Method> (any value is ok as this value is not required at the 
target)
<ID>123456</ID> (any value is ok as this value is not required at the 
target)
</Detail1>
<Detail2>
<TransactionID>89NpvkBIi0TLxAssskdHtIETUa</TransactionID>
<USERID>xyz@abc.super</USERID>
<APIPUBLISHER>admin</APIPUBLISHER>
<API>Test_API_/zones/{zoning}</API>
<Hits>1</Hits>
<Starttime>2018-09-12 11:09:17</Starttime> (any time is ok as this value is 
not required at the target)
<EndTime>2018-09-12 11:09:17</EndTime>   (any time is ok as this value is 
not required at the target)
<Rate>10</Rate> (any value is ok as this value is not required at the 
target)
<Amount>90</Amount>  (any value is ok as this value is not required at the 
target)
<Currency>EURO</Currency>
<Channel1>test</Channel1> 
<Channel2>time</Channel2>
<Region>dummy</Region>
<TIME>2018-09-25 11:09:12</TIME>  (this value has seconds also as it was not 
there in input file)
<Share>dumy</Share>   (any value is ok as this value is not required at the 
target)
<Method>dummy</Method> (any value is ok as this value is not required at the 
target)
<ID>123456</ID>   (any value is ok as this value is not required at the 
target)
</Detail2>
```

Can you please help me with some input so that this can be achieved. Thanks in advance...
Please guide.

I have tested with this code:

```
<xsl:stylesheetxmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
version="1.0">
<xsl:templatematch="@*|node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templatesselect="@*|node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:templatematch="Hits">
<xsl:copy-ofselect="."/>
<Starttime>2018-08-1011:09:17</Starttime>
<EndTime>2018-08-1111:51:17</EndTime>
<Rate>10</Rate>
<Amount>90</Amount>
<Amount>EURO</Amount>
<Channel1>test</Channel1>
<Channel2>time</Channel2>
<Region>dummy</Region>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:templatematch="Time">
<xsl:copy-ofselect="."/>
<Share>dumy</Share>
<Method>dummy</Method>
<ID>123456</ID>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It does not fail and does not perform any activity. I am new into it may be I am doing wrong. Could you please guide..

Comment: What have you tried? Hope you are not asking a "Give me teh codez" question.

Comment: I have added the code which was tried.